# Functions inside Object using Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

Hi I am using Angular 9.
In JavaScript, We can able to write function inside Object like

```
let Set_Of_Data = {
    data : "12",
    method : function(test) { return something; }
}
```

How to do this in typescript?

Comment: What issue do you face with this code?

Comment: This also works in typescript, why shouln't it?

Comment: you can also use flat arrow: `method : (test)=>{ return something; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to define the types or assign default values, you can do it like below:

```
interface SetOfData {
  data: string;
  method(): string;
}

let setOfData: SetOfData = {
  data : "12",
  method : function(xyz = ' xyz') { 
    const abc = 'abc ';
    return abc + this.data + xyz; 
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not name your interfaces using snake-case convention like that. Prefer PascalCase convention naming  : SetOfData instead of Set_Of_data. For your variables, prefer using camelCase convention, so setOfData instead of Set_Of_Data.

Comment: Also you don't **have** to define separate types, compiler will infer it. But it's a good idea if you are reusing it.

Comment: Can you please give detailed example @BalázsÉdes

Comment: yeah, naming conventions can be followed accordingly, I just used the snippet provided in the question itself. I am only trying to show how the types can be enforced in a strict manner.

Comment: As @BalázsÉdes said you don't have to declare the type upfront: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzuDyBmARAhmZEC8EDeBYAUBBACaroBcEARAIwBMVANAUQLbgAWA9sRJfAFcAdgGMwASy5CAFAA8AngC9MEAOQQFi1QEocEFkQgipUSMgBGIlaotXVAbgNEATuAHOhEWxADUEMBziUAB0pGi+Gkr2+oQQAL4EcUA) The code OP has should work as is (except it's referencing a variable that doesn't exist but that's probably for illustrative purpose). Point being that the code is *already* TypeScript and it's unclear what OP really needs to do.